# Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, config, babeljs

I am following a tutorial for setting up react with webpack and babel but i am getting errors.

I have tried re-installing all modules but it didn't worked. I have also matched my config codes still no luck.

> ReactJs@1.0.0 create C:\Users\Gourav Thakur\Desktop\Me Creative\github_codebase\ReactJs
>   webpack

Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: 854e6cae7eaf01829eca
Version: webpack 4.30.0
Time: 82ms
Built at: 04/28/2019 2:01:14 PM

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Gourav Thakur\Desktop\Me Creative\github_codebase\ReactJs'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! ReactJs@1.0.0 create: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ReactJs@1.0.0 create script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gourav Thakur\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-28T08_31_14_980Z-debug.log

[image: Error message]
![Error][1]

[image: Directory structure]
![Directory structure][2]

[image: webpack.config.js]
![webpack.config.js][3]

[image: Package.json]
![package.json][4]

[image: index.js]
![index.js][5]

Comment: May I know why your are setting up a react project manually when you can use `create react-project` which will setup everything for you and then if you need to tweak the configs you can eject it.

Comment: @Ayan I am setting up manually to know how all the pieces fit together. Setting up a react environment manually is challenging for beginners. That's why I wanted to learn how webpack, babel and react all fit together. create react-app is for pro who doesn't want to waste time configuring everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webpack@4 default value for entry:

> By default its value is ./src/index.js, but you can specify a different (or >multiple entry points) by configuring the entry property in the webpack >configuration.

To add a custom entry point, update your webpack as mentioned below. Moreover, move your webpack config file to the root folder.

`entry: path.resolve(__dirname) + '/path/to/your/index.js',`

However, in the new version of webpack 4.29.* you don't need a webpack config file anymore, so you use the command below to bundle it

```
webpack ./app/index.js --output ./dist/app.bundle.js --mode development
```

Comment: I moved webpack.config.js to the root and edited the entry point. Now it shows me this error : 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gouravthakur39/fcc-project-assests/master/6.jpg
@murtaza-hussain

Answer (score 3):

The `webpack.config.js` should be in the root directory (ReactJs) and not inside the `app` folder.

Comment: Thanks Rannie , solved my problem. Indeed not in the app folder otherwise it can't find the entry module.