# Can't resolve './src' after webpack update - how to adjust a previously working config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am struggling to update webpack from version 2.7.0 to version 4.40.2. These are the errors:

```
webpack is watching the files…
Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.
Version: webpack 4.40.2
Time: 42ms
Built at: 2019-09-16 12:34:56
WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\myUIproject\'
Process terminated with code 0.
```

Leaving the warning about the missing `--mode=development` asside, my previously working `Webpack.config.js` (see below) is no longer working: `Can't resolve './src'`.

There is already an Stackoverflow post on that [Can't resolve './src'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888833/8330162), the solution given there is to delete the webpack config file altogether, but instead use something like this:

```
webpack ./src/index.tsx --output ./dist/bundle.js --mode development
```

I adjusted that to my architecture (I hoped), but I am getting the following error which means that I did not:

```
Version: webpack 4.40.2
Time: 42ms
Built at: 2019-09-16 12:34:56
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  4.13 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[./src/index.tsx] 350 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 51:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
|         <Provider store={store}>
|             <Layout>
```

May you please help me how to correctly define my entry point?

#### Supplementary information

My `Webpack.config.js` which worked for webpack 2.7.0 looks as follows

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "bundle": ["babel-polyfill", "whatwg-fetch", "./src/index.tsx"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [[
                        'env',
                        {
                            "targets": {
                                "browsers": ["ie >= 11"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]]
                }
            },"ts-loader"] },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!less-loader") }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css")
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating this to `module.rules` instead of `module.loaders`?

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
      { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

See the [webpack loader docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/).

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [[
                        'env',
                        {
                            "targets": {
                                "browsers": ["ie >= 11"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]]
                }
            },"ts-loader"] },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css-loader!less-loader") }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have to confess that I do not know much about `webpack`, other then [why we use it](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/why-webpack/), so I would appreciate if you could explain your idea a bit. I am really after the minimal solution, and I find the idea of having just two webpack command line in my `package.json` pretty appealing.