# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, webpack

Im trying to run npm run dev in my root directory, but I get this error:

npm run dev

```
> dev
> npm run development


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] Unknown argument: --hide-modules
? Which flags do you want to use? ... 
√ Which flags do you want to use? · No items were selected
[webpack-cli]
Executing CLI

asset main.js 644 bytes [emitted] (name: main)

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\project'

webpack 5.2.0 compiled with 1 error in 56 ms
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-26T01_53_38_098Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "npm run development"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-26T01_53_38_149Z-debug.log
```

I have searched in everywhere but I cant find a solution! Any ideas?!?!

Comment: you need to check where  `'./src'` used and fix that

Comment: Managed to run into the same problem. Fresh laravel install, added laravel-ui and getting this...

Comment: Please share more details - this does not look like a PHP error to me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `Laravel 8.24.1` and I had to move the `webpack.config.js` out of the `\app` folder. Saw the suggestion from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888598/entry-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-src).